# Undefined ERROR javascript value with space in between

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create javascript shopping cart however with this code

```
        <!-- Main -->
        <div class="container">
            <div class="masonry searchable-container">
            <div class="row">
             <div class="item items">
                <div class="card" style="width: 20rem;">
          <img class="card-img-top" src="http://www.azspagirls.com/files/2010/09/orange.jpg" alt="Card image cap">
          <div class="card-block">
            <h4 class="card-title">Orange</h4>
            <p class="card-text">Price: $0.5</p>
            <a href="#" data-name="Orange" data-price="0.5" class="add-to-cart btn btn-primary">Add to cart</a>
          </div>
        </div>
              </div>
              <div class="item items">
                <div class="card" style="width: 20rem;">
          <img class="card-img-top" src="http://images.all-free-download.com/images/graphicthumb/vector_illustration_of_ripe_bananas_567893.jpg" alt="Card image cap">
          <div class="card-block">
            <h4 class="card-title">Banana</h4>
            <p class="card-text">Price: $1.22</p>
            <a href="#" data-name="Banana" data-price="1.22" class="add-to-cart btn btn-primary">Add to cart</a>
          </div>
        </div>
              </div>
             <div class="item items">
                <div class="card" style="width: 20rem;">
          <img class="card-img-top" src="https://3.imimg.com/data3/IC/JO/MY-9839190/organic-lemon-250x250.jpg" alt="Card image cap">
          <div class="card-block">
            <h4 class="card-title">Lemon</h4>
            <p class="card-text">Price: $5</p>
            <a href="#" data-name="Lemon" data-price="5" class="add-to-cart btn btn-primary">Add to cart</a>
          </div>
        </div>
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>


         <!-- Modal -->

              <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Cart</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                  <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-body">
                <table class="show-cart table">

                </table>
                <div>Total price: $<span class="total-cart"></span></div>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Order now</button>
              </div>
  <script src='js/jquery.min.js'></script><script  src="js/script.js"></script>
```

the problem here is that "data-name" value does not work with spaces between or more than one word if something 'Green bananas' if i try to add quantity or delete item in cart, it shows "undefined" it allows only for one word. I am new in javascript, May anyone assist me on this one.

here is the javascript code below

```
        // ************************************************
    // Shopping Cart API
    // ************************************************

    var shoppingCart = (function() {
      // =============================
      // Private methods and propeties
      // =============================
      cart = [];

      // Constructor
      function Item(name, price, count) {
        this.name = name;
        this.price = price;
        this.count = count;
      }

      // Save cart
      function saveCart() {
        sessionStorage.setItem('shoppingCart', JSON.stringify(cart));
      }

        // Load cart
      function loadCart() {
        cart = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('shoppingCart'));
      }
      if (sessionStorage.getItem("shoppingCart") != null) {
        loadCart();
      }


      // =============================
      // Public methods and propeties
      // =============================
      var obj = {};

      // Add to cart
      obj.addItemToCart = function(name, price, count) {
        for(var item in cart) {
          if(cart[item].name === name) {
            cart[item].count ++;
            saveCart();
            return;
          }
        }
        var item = new Item(name, price, count);
        cart.push(item);
        saveCart();
      }
      // Set count from item
      obj.setCountForItem = function(name, count) {
        for(var i in cart) {
          if (cart[i].name === name) {
            cart[i].count = count;
            break;
          }
        }
      };
      // Remove item from cart
      obj.removeItemFromCart = function(name) {
          for(var item in cart) {
            if(cart[item].name === name) {
              cart[item].count --;
              if(cart[item].count === 0) {
                cart.splice(item, 1);
              }
              break;
            }
        }
        saveCart();
      }

      // Remove all items from cart
      obj.removeItemFromCartAll = function(name) {
        for(var item in cart) {
          if(cart[item].name === name) {
            cart.splice(item, 1);
            break;
          }
        }
        saveCart();
      }

      // Clear cart
      obj.clearCart = function() {
        cart = [];
        saveCart();
      }

      // Count cart 
      obj.totalCount = function() {
        var totalCount = 0;
        for(var item in cart) {
          totalCount += cart[item].count;
        }
        return totalCount;
      }

      // Total cart
      obj.totalCart = function() {
        var totalCart = 0;
        for(var item in cart) {
          totalCart += cart[item].price * cart[item].count;
        }
        return Number(totalCart.toFixed(2));
      }

      // List cart
      obj.listCart = function() {
        var cartCopy = [];
        for(i in cart) {
          item = cart[i];
          itemCopy = {};
          for(p in item) {
            itemCopy[p] = item[p];

          }
          itemCopy.total = Number(item.price * item.count).toFixed(2);
          cartCopy.push(itemCopy)
        }
        return cartCopy;
      }

      // cart : Array
      // Item : Object/Class
      // addItemToCart : Function
      // removeItemFromCart : Function
      // removeItemFromCartAll : Function
      // clearCart : Function
      // countCart : Function
      // totalCart : Function
      // listCart : Function
      // saveCart : Function
      // loadCart : Function
      return obj;
    })();


    // *****************************************
    // Triggers / Events
    // ***************************************** 
    // Add item
    $('.add-to-cart').click(function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      var name = $(this).data('name');
      var price = Number($(this).data('price'));
      shoppingCart.addItemToCart(name, price, 1);
      displayCart();
    });

    // Clear items
    $('.clear-cart').click(function() {
      shoppingCart.clearCart();
      displayCart();
    });


    function displayCart() {
      var cartArray = shoppingCart.listCart();
      var output = "";
      for(var i in cartArray) {
        output += "<tr>"
          + "<td>" + cartArray[i].name + "</td>" 
          + "<td>(" + cartArray[i].price + ")</td>"
          + "<td><div class='input-group'><button class='minus-item input-group-addon btn btn-primary' data-name=" + cartArray[i].name + ">-</button>"
          + "<input type='number' class='item-count form-control' data-name='" + cartArray[i].name + "' value='" + cartArray[i].count + "'>"
          + "<button class='plus-item btn btn-primary input-group-addon' data-name=" + cartArray[i].name + ">+</button></div></td>"
          + "<td><button class='delete-item btn btn-danger' data-name=" + cartArray[i].name + ">X</button></td>"
          + " = " 
          + "<td>" + cartArray[i].total + "</td>" 
          +  "</tr>";
      }
      $('.show-cart').html(output);
      $('.total-cart').html(shoppingCart.totalCart());
      $('.total-count').html(shoppingCart.totalCount());
    }

    // Delete item button

    $('.show-cart').on("click", ".delete-item", function(event) {
      var name = $(this).data('name')
      shoppingCart.removeItemFromCartAll(name);
      displayCart();
    })


    // -1
    $('.show-cart').on("click", ".minus-item", function(event) {
      var name = $(this).data('name')
      shoppingCart.removeItemFromCart(name);
      displayCart();
    })
    // +1
    $('.show-cart').on("click", ".plus-item", function(event) {
      var name = $(this).data('name')
      shoppingCart.addItemToCart(name);
      displayCart();
    })

    // Item count input
    $('.show-cart').on("change", ".item-count", function(event) {
       var name = $(this).data('name');
       var count = Number($(this).val());
      shoppingCart.setCountForItem(name, count);
      displayCart();
    });

    displayCart();
```

Comment: You would probably need double quotes in here: `data-name='" + cartArray[i].name + "'` so try this: `data-name=\"" + cartArray[i].name + "\"`

Comment: perfect ! working fine

Comment: Added it as the answer to your question. :)

Answer (score 0):

You would probably need double quotes in here:

```
data-name='" + cartArray[i].name + "'
```

So they will need to be escaped like this:

```
data-name=\"" + cartArray[i].name + "\"
```